# A Star PathFinding and enemy Movement in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding

hi i have a problem with A star Pathfinding.
i have a simple game ,  put some towers (game object) and 1 enemy starts to reach a destination.
the problem is enemy stucks and tryes push tower, since i fixed tower , it cant force it.

[image]

try  to change  Ai Path Of enemy (radius)  but still it try to push towers.
changed "Diameter" in 2d in Path Find Graph but still it try push them.
checked Enable Rotation , it passes that area hardly and slowly.
in image , The red area is slow part. and   showed scanned Graph.

[image]

need to tell top Tiles Are in Layer which graph wont able to find a path.

what   am doing wrong? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Obstacle Layer:** Make sure that the towers are marked as obstacles in the pathfinding graph. If the towers are not considered obstacles, the enemy might try to push them instead of finding a path around them. Ensure that the pathfinding algorithm understands which parts of the map are impassable.
2. **Navmesh Navigation:** Consider using a navmesh-based pathfinding approach. Navmeshes offer more precise pathfinding around obstacles and can lead to better results than grid-based approaches, especially in complex environments with various obstacles.
3. **Agent Settings:** Check the settings of the enemy AI agent. Make sure the radius or size of the agent is appropriate to allow it to move around the towers comfortably without trying to push them.
4. **Costs and Weights:** Adjust the pathfinding costs and weights to encourage the agent to avoid certain areas, such as the top tiles that are causing the issue. You can assign higher costs to certain tiles, making them less desirable paths for the agent.
5. **Dynamic Obstacles:** If the towers can be moved or change their positions during the game, consider implementing dynamic obstacle handling in your pathfinding algorithm. This way, the pathfinding system can adapt to changes in the environment and find new paths when the towers are moved.
6. **Tight Spaces:** If the red area is a narrow passage, the enemy may have difficulty navigating through it. In such cases, consider increasing the resolution of your pathfinding grid or using more sophisticated pathfinding techniques, such as funnel algorithms, to handle tight spaces better.
7. **Path Smoothing:** Implement path smoothing techniques to ensure that the path followed by the enemy is more natural and less likely to get stuck in small gaps between obstacles.
8. **Debugging Tools:** Use pathfinding debugging tools to visualize the pathfinding process and identify any potential issues or bottlenecks in the algorithm. Unity's NavMesh Debug Visualization can be helpful in understanding how the pathfinding algorithm is behaving.
9. **Check Node Connections:** Inspect the pathfinding graph to ensure that all nodes are correctly connected. If some nodes are not connected as expected, the pathfinding algorithm may struggle to find a valid path.